# Install Windows XP .iso on USB (Linux, Lubuntu)

Tags: system-installation, usb, windows, iso

I have windows xp iso file, and I want to upload it on a usb (pendrive). 
Then I want to install the Windows on my computer. 
How can I burn the windows .iso file on my pendrive?

Answer (score -2):

I've used this **universal usb installer** successfully for putting an iso on a usb and to make it bootable:

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/

*pendrivelinux* dot *com*

Note: I have had issues using a Ubuntu system to successfully list all the drives (in particular, my USB I was using), but 100% success using it on a windows box.

Comment: The described tool only works for Linux distros.